# What would you substitute for { and } in Mathematica code so it will display in YouTube comments?

Tags: formatting

Curly braces are not allowed in YouTube comments, so it would be good to find another character that Mathematica doesn't use and YouTube will allow so a global find and replace will put back the braces.

Comment: Would `List[..]` work? Then no change is needed when pasting into Mma.

Comment: @Michael E2 -  Yes!  That works.

Comment: Oops, this might be hopeless: < and > are not allowed.

Comment: If `[` and `]` are allowed, then `FullForm[expr]` of your expressions `expr` might work.  `FullForm` is not the easiest to read, but it can be pasted into Mma.

Comment: @ Michael E2  How can FullForm be used in: ```For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++, Print[i]] ?

Comment: `For[Set[i, 1], LessEqual[i, 10], Increment[i], Print[i]]`? But `Do[Print[i], {i, 10}]` is much better.

Comment: That's great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

*Conversion of @Michael E2's comment to a community wiki answer:*

**@Michael E2:**

Would `List[..]` work? Then no change is needed when pasting into Mma.